fmpeg piped output is always providing an empty frame
I am trying to capture a webcam using the ffmpeg command in a Python script and process the frame for my work. For my work, I need to capture and forward through the pipe to my function, but I always get an empty frame. I tried many SO solutions, but they are not helping.
  ffmpeg_command = 'ffmpeg -f v4l2 -framerate 25 -video_size 960x540
  -pix_fmt yuyv422 -i /dev/video0     \
  -f rawvideo \
  -pix_fmt yuyv422 \
   pipe:'

  pro = subprocess.Popen(ffmpeg_command.split(),stdout=subprocess.PIPE,shell=True)
            
  while True:
        raw_frame = pro.stdout.read(960*540*3)  #i tried all possible values here
        frame = np.frombuffer(raw_frame,dtype=np.uint8)
        frame = frame.reshape((960,540, 3)) # getting error here as empty 

I am not sure what mistake I am making.
Any help is appreciated. 

Don't use split() with shell=True. Ideally, stop using either split() or shell=True and define your argument list as a Python list explicitly (which is to say: ffmpeg_command = ['ffmpeg', '-f', 'v4l2', ...])

In particular, when you use both split() and shell=True at the same time (and you're on a UNIX system -- I have no idea what the effect of combining these is on Windows), only the first element of the resulting list is treated as code to execute by the shell; extra elements go into $0, $1 and so forth, but since the string passed at code in your case is just ffmpeg and it doesn't look at what $0/$1/etc are, they're all just ignored.

...which is all to say that you're starting the process incorrectly, so it's normal/expected that there's no output available to read at all.

Yes @CharlesDuffy you are correct after removing shell=True or split command it worked for me . But the same its failing if i give in the usual format command = ['ffmpeg -f v4l2 -framerate 25 -video_size 960x540 -pix_fmt yuyv422 -i /dev/video0     
-f rawvideo -pix_fmt yuyv422 
-']
why is it so ?. sorry i am not expert in python.

What do you means "usual format "? Do you use list with single string? command = ['string_in_list'] ? When shell=True then it has to be single string without list - command = 'string_without_list' - and shell will split it before sending to system. And when you use shell=False then you have to split it into list like ['ffmpeg', '-f', 'v4l2', ...] - every elements has to be separate - and it will send it directly to system (which expects it as list of separate elements, not single string).

BTW: if you have to split it (using code) then Python has shlex.split() for this. But usually it is simpler to define it as list in code - because it allows to use if/else to add or skip some elements. And late you can use "".join(list) to create one string (or use shlex.join())

i am able to do with split and disabling shell=True even in single list , thanks
